# Only able to read one byte via serial

Tags: python, c, windows, linux, serial-port

I've got a C/Python setup on my machine, I'm doing some testing with serial communications and for some reason I'm never reading more than 1 byte back.

My set up: I have a windows 7 machine, running OpenSUSE in a virtual box. I have 2 USB-RS232 converters and an adaptor between them (so it's a loop from one usb port to the other).

On the Windows side I was able to get them to communicate with each other via Python-to-Python, and C-to-Python. Once I use the Linux VM, I can get data from the C (Linux) to the Python (Windows), but when I do it the other way around I only get 1 byte back. I'm thinking it's something wrong with how I open the file or execute the read on the Linux C code, but I'm not sure what could be the issue.

Python Code (using PySerial):

```
>>> import serial
>>> ser = serial.Serial(3)
>>> ser
Serial<id=0x2491780, open=True>(port='COM4', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, 
parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=None, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False)
>>> ser.read(5)
'Hello'
>>> ser.write("hi you")
6L
```

The C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <termios.h>

int open_port()
{
    int fd;
    fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
    if(fd < 0)
      perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyUSB0 - ");
    else
      fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);
    return fd;
}

int swrite(int fd, char * str)
{
    int n;
    n = write(fd, str, strlen(str));
    if (n<0)
        printf("write() of %d bytes failed\n", strlen(str));
    return n;
}

int main()
{
    int fd, databytes;
    char buf[100] = {0};
    struct termios options;

    fd = open_port();

    //Set the baud rate to 9600 to match
    tcgetattr(fd, &options);
    cfsetispeed(&options, B9600);
    cfsetospeed(&options, B9600);
    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);
    tcgetattr(fd, &options);

    databytes = swrite(fd, "Hello");
    if(databytes > 0)
      printf("Wrote %d bytes\n", databytes);

    databytes = read(fd, buf, 100);
    if(databytes < 0)
      printf("Error! No bytes read\n");
    else
      printf("We read %d bytes, message: %s\n", databytes, buf);

    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

And I'm getting back:

```
mike@linux-4puc:~> gcc serial_com.c
mike@linux-4puc:~> ./a.out 
Wrote 5 bytes
We read 1 bytes, message: h
```

So the Linux->Windows write is working, python is showing the correct "Hello" string, but for some reason I'm only getting one byte back on the Windows->Linux side of things.

Anyone see anything wrong?

**EDIT:**
Based on the feedback that I've gotten, I've tried two tweaks to the code. Sounds like I can't guarantee that all the data will be there, so I've tried:

1) a sleep

```
    if(databytes > 0)
      printf("Wrote %d bytes\n", databytes);
    sleep(15);                 // Hack one to get the data there in time, worked
    databytes = read(fd, buf, 100);
```

2) a while loop

```
while(1){  // Hack two to catch the data that wasn't read the first time. Failed
           // this only saw 'h' like before then sat waiting on the read()
  databytes = read(fd, buf, 100);
  if(databytes < 0)
    printf("Error! No bytes read\n");
  else
    printf("We read %d bytes, message: %s\n", databytes, buf);
}
```

Seems the loop doesn't work, so does the data not read get trashed??
**/EDIT**

Comment: Re-reading your original problem -- it sounds like you haven't ever been able to receive data from the linux side. Have you confirmed that the linux drivers are working correctly at all? USB-RS232 converters can be very finicky beasts, and some chipsets are not well supported at all. I would test the port with something like minicom to make sure that it the device is working before troubleshooting your own code any further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got some good answers and incite on this (+1's all around!), while all of the answers lead to correct conclusions (about read not getting the data), none of the input actually "fixed" the problem I was having.

Here's how I got this to work finally:

The settings in the `termios` structure were killing me. While I was setting **some** of the flags, I wasn't setting all of them. So this:

```
tcgetattr(fd, &options);
cfsetispeed(&options, B9600);
cfsetospeed(&options, B9600);
tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);
```

Changed to this:

```
tcgetattr(fd, &options);
cfsetispeed(&options, B19200);
cfsetospeed(&options, B19200);
options.c_iflag = 0; // Disable Input flags
options.c_lflag = 0; // Disable Local mode flags
options.c_oflag = 0; // Disable Output flags
options.c_cflag = (options.c_cflag & ~CSIZE) | CS8; //Data bits per character (8)
options.c_cc[VMIN] = 50;  // Wait for 50 characters or
options.c_cc[VTIME] = 50; // Wait for 5 seconds
options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD | HUPCL);   // Ignore modem status lines, 
                                               // enable receiver, 
                                               // and hang up on last close
options.c_cflag &= ~(PARENB | PARODD); //Clearing even and odd parity
options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;            //Clear double stop bits
tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);
```

With these changes now I get the data in my C Linux code that I write from Python.

I used these two sources for a lot of "facts" about what the options are for the `termios` structure:

1. [flag description](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.2/neutrino/lib_ref/t/termios.html)
2. [Quick Overview](http://www.unixguide.net/unix/programming/3.6.2.shtml)

Answer (score 7):

From the [read(2) manual](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read);

> On success, the number of bytes read is returned (zero indicates end
>   of file), and the file position is advanced by this number. **It is not
>   an error if this number is smaller than the number of bytes requested;
>   this may happen for example because fewer bytes are actually available
>   right now (maybe because we were close to end-of-file, or because we
>   are reading from a pipe, or from a terminal)**

In other words, since you read from the socket right after writing and your computer is quite a lot faster than the serial port, *there is most likely only a single character available to read* and `read(2)` returns only that character.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Please see my edit, but from your post it sounded like the data was simply not present yet. Adding a `sleep()` to allow for extra time confirmed this... but why can't I loop and read the data? Seems that fails. (test #2 above)

Comment: @Mike Don't have a serial port handy to test, but just to be sure it's not an issue, could you zero-terminate `buf` before printing it with `%s`?

Comment: I was already initializing it to 0 at the start: `char buf[100] = {0};` so after the `read()` the next char in buf should already be `'\0'`, or we're you asking for something else?

Comment: @Mike Oops, missed the init. You should indeed be receiving the next few bytes of data when calling `read()` again. No other output than the 'h' line seems to indicate that the serial handshake has halted transmission of the rest. Is Python still returning '6L' for the write line?

Answer (score 4):

The man page for [read](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) says

> ...attempts to read up to count bytes...

Your code looks like it assumes the full buffer will always be returned by a single `read`; its valid for the data to be returned over several calls.

It'd also be good practice to check for `read` returning -1 with `errno == EINTR` and retry after this (use `TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY` if running on a GNU system).  `read` may return a transient error if it is interrupted by a signal.

Comment: `valid for the data to be returned over several calls` - Wouldn't this mean my edit #2 above should have worked? If I loop and only get 1 char the first time, then I should get more chars the second read?

Comment: @Mike I'd expect you to get more chars on the second read.  The last paragraph of my answer explains why this sometimes won't be the case. Can you try reading again in the case where errno == EINTR ?

Answer (score 4):

As others have answered, the C read() function is fulfilling its contract by only returning a single byte.

The C read() and Python read() functions are quite different.

PySerial says, about read(),

> Read size bytes from the serial port. If a timeout is set it may return less characters as requested. With no timeout it will block until the requested number of bytes is read.

While the C API makes no such guarantee. It will return any characters which are available in the buffer, (even 0, if there's nothing there yet).

If you want the C side to behave like the Python side, you'll need to use a different function. Something like this:

```
int read_exact_chars(int fildes, char *buf, size_t nbyte)
{
    ssize_t chars_read;
    int chars_left = nbyte;
    while (chars_left) {
        chars_read = read(fildes, buf, chars_left)
        if (chars_read == -1) {
            /* An error occurred; bail out early. The caller will see that
               we read fewer bytes than requested, and can check errno
             */
            break;
        } else {
            buf += chars_read;
            chars_left -= chars_read;
        }
    }
    /* return the actual number of characters read */
    return nbyte - chars_left;
}
```

Comment: For all intents and purposes, isn't my edit (the second example) the same as yours? I'm continuing to read and display, but only the first byte ever comes in.

Comment: Well, maybe not for *all* intents and purposes :) My code is emulating the behaviour of the python read() function; yours reads everything available on the port for as long as it's open. But yeah, they're both reading in a loop and shouldn't stop after the first character. That might indicate that something else is wrong.